# Why is cross_val_score different to when I calculate it manually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is the **reproducible** example code:

```
from numpy import mean
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, weights = [0.3,0.7], n_features=100, n_informative=75, random_state=0)
# define the model
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=0)
# evaluate the model
n_splits=10
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits, random_state=0)
n_scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring='balanced_accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
# report performance
print('Accuracy: %0.4f' % (mean(n_scores['test_score'])))

bal_acc_sum = []
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
    model.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])                                      
    bal_acc_sum.append(balanced_accuracy_score(model.predict(X[test_index]),y[test_index]))

print(f"Accuracy: %0.4f" % (mean(bal_acc_sum)))
```

Result:

```
Accuracy: 0.6737
Accuracy: 0.7113
```

The results for my self calculated accuracy is always higher than the one cross-validation gives me. But it should be the same or am I missing something? Same metric, same split (KFold brings same result), same fixed model (other models behave identically), same random state, but different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because, in your manual calculation,  you have flipped the order of arguments in `balanced_accuracy_score`, which matters - it should be `(y_true, y_pred)` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html)).

Changing this, your manual calculation becomes:

```
bal_acc_sum = []
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
    model.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])                                      
    bal_acc_sum.append(balanced_accuracy_score(y[test_index], model.predict(X[test_index])))  # change order of arguments here

print(f"Accuracy: %0.4f" % (mean(bal_acc_sum)))
```

Result:

```
Accuracy: 0.6737
```

And

```
import numpy as np
np.all(bal_acc_sum==n_scores['test_score'])
# True
```